# Creating a custom glossy volume shader with reflections?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation, volumetrics, osl

I've imported a whitewater fluid simulation made in Houdini as a VDB and have managed to render it using the Principled Volume BSDF, but without the specular/reflection highlights that whitewater usually has. In Houdini, it's possible to create a custom reflective volume shader, with which the whitewater can be properly rendered: https://vimeo.com/97655862. Would such a thing be possible in Cycles? Perhaps using OSL shaders? Thanks

Comment: You can use the *Surface* and *Volume* material outputs at the same time, if that's what you're asking.  The glossy/specular light reactions could come from a *Principled BSDF*

Comment: Does whitewater output fluid simulations in the form of a volume, like a flip smoke simulation does?